# How to supply filtered series (data range) to chart?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a table with X-Y values for two types of measurements, I want to draw two graph lines on a chart for each of the type (without modification of data in the sheet)

| x-values | y-values | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | A |
| 0 | 6 | B |
| 1 | 3 | A |
| 1 | 2 | B |

alternative would be to use 2columns table, but I would have to transform data from source which i would like to avoid

| x-values | y-Avalues | y-Bvalues |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | 6 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |

[image: desired graph]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). I do not think there is a way to use a filter or formula in a chart data range definition, so you will probably have to recast the data in order to plot it the way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose **Insert > Sheet** and put this formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet to pivot the data the way need:

```
=query( 
  Sheet1!A1:C, 
  "select A, max(B) 
   where A is not null 
   group by A 
   pivot C", 
  1 
)
```

Then insert a chart based on the data in the new sheet.

Comment: Thanks, cool trick!